# Assistance with bash, shell script syntax error

Tags: linux

A former network engineer was using Xymon for node monitoring. This shell script was previously used to compare actively monitored nodes against the routing table of our core switch and output data accordingly to show any new networks.

Attempts to execute the shell script now return error:

```
    awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
```

Here's the commands applied to shell script:

```
    cat /var/lib/rancid/dnow/configs/ushouston-dnw1-cr01 | awk '/display ip routing-table/{flag=1;next}/display vlan all/{flag=0}f$
    ROUTELIST=$(grep -E "\.0/2[2,3,4]" /tmp/routes.txt | grep -v 192.168.13.1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1"\."$2"\."$3}$
    for ROUTE in $ROUTELIST ; do
            CHECK=$(grep -w $ROUTE /etc/hosts)
            if [ "$CHECK" = "" ] ; then
                    echo "$ROUTE is not monitored"
            fi
    done
```

Any assistance or guidance understanding why the error is received and what needs to be adjusted is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I failed to mention this is a Linux system, kernel version 3.16.0-44-generic.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. It probably comes from the `"\."` bits. No idea what the author was thinking with that.

Comment: The author was probably confused between regular expressions and ordinary strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is coming from this:

```
{print $1"\."$2"\."$3}
```

There's no need to escape `.` in ordinary strings, only in regular expressions. That should be:

```
{print $1"."$2"."$3}
```